# Align view in quadview mode

Tags: python, 3d-view, operator

I want to align the 3D view like the menu item "View/Align View/Center Cursor and View All" does it, but with Python. If in "Scripting" layout this works fine with the following code:

```
import bpy
override = {}
override['window'] = bpy.context.window
override['scene' ] = bpy.context.scene
override['screen'] = bpy.context.screen
override['area'  ] = bpy.context.screen.areas[2]
override['region'] = bpy.context.screen.areas[2].regions[4]
bpy.ops.view3d.view_all(override, center = True)
```

But it does not work if the view is in quadview mode; only the view in the lower left corner is aligned then.
I tried to replace the region line by

```
override['region'] = bpy.context.screen.areas[2].space.active.region_quadviews[x]
```

(x = 0..3) but this fails because the region_quadviews[x] are of type RegionView3D instead of type Region. Is it possible to get four regions of type Region of a quadview?

Strange: Clicking on the menu item shows the same behaviour, i. e. only the lower left view is aligned; but using the shortcut (Shift-C) aligns the view the mousepointer is over - this is my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bpy
override = {}
override['window'] = bpy.context.window
override['scene' ] = bpy.context.scene
override['screen'] = bpy.context.screen
override['area'  ] = bpy.context.screen.areas[2]

for region in [r for r in bpy.context.screen.areas[2].regions if r.type == 'WINDOW']:
    override['region'] = region
    bpy.ops.view3d.view_all(override, center=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I combined this solution with this one [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/getting-the-active-region) and can align the quadview quarter where the mousepointer is over. Perfect.

Comment: I want to solve same problem, but for Node Editor. "bpy.ops.node.view_all(override)" is not working