# How to run a modal operator for/in several 3D Views (video of problem included)

Tags: python, scripting, operator

When i invoke a modal operator (it highlights faces under the mouse cursor via raycast and bgl) from the tool shelf, it is running in/for the 3D View, the tool shelf is in but not in other 3D Views displaying the same content.
I need to invoke the modal operator again from the others 3D Views toolshelfs to get the desired effect. Is there a way to invoke it for all 3D Views at once?

Because it is not easy to explain i made a short video (30 sec) to show the problem:
https://youtu.be/ogTSyeIRbNA

edit: i cannot mark as duplicate but the question was kinda answered here already(it was hard to find for me without the hint from batFINGER):

[How can I disable Right Click at my UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101792/how-can-i-disable-right-click-at-my-ui/101894#101894)

[Getting the active region](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/getting-the-active-region)

[RegionView3D from Region object and vice versa](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23453/regionview3d-from-region-object-and-vice-versa)

Comment: My guess without seeing any code is [try this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94022/15543) ie get your mouse coordinates from the screen and use that to calculate where you are in the region of another area.

Comment: I thought that pushed me in the right direction and i found this, too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/getting-the-active-region but i still cannot get it to work. I will add some code to my question.

Comment: And [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101894/15543) Thought I'd done something similar recently.  Get your area and region from the screen.

Comment: Ok,  will look into it tomorrow and report back

Comment: @batFINGER It works. Took me a while to figure it out because i forgot to use context.area.tag_redraw() on all view_3d and not just the context one.